# Publish a software with copyright and license

Tags: licensing, copyright

I just read some artical about publishing software and I am personally developing some random metero application at the moment.

The artical were suggesting the software should have a publisher website.

But what I have to put down in the publisher website to keep my copyright?

Is it simply really just "Designed/Developed @ 2012 By King Chan" at the bottom of the site and software and is enough?

Or do I have to even write a long paragraph of license/agreement said the user who download/use the software cannot copy the icon/functionality etc?

(The Apple and Samsung things get me worry about CopyRight now....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost certainly own the copyright on your code (1)

You don't need to do anything to claim that - although putting an explicit claim in the code makes it clearer.

A license is there to control what other people can do with your code (MIT requires them to mention you, GPL requires that they also make their code GPL etc). If you don't want to put any extra restrictions on users of your code then you don't need to do anything.

1 - unless you are in some weird country that isn't in the Berne convention. Or if your employer claims copyright on anything you do and you live somewhere that would uphold this.

Comment: So I don't to register anything specially on any site too?

Comment: No - you CAN register things with the US copyright office which gives you advantages in court in proving that you had the idea first. But there is no need to do anything

Comment: I am in Canada, is it depends on where I live? Or where the place I sell to?  Just want to know beforehand.

Comment: Not for most civilized countries (including Canada) see  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention_for_the_Protection_of_Literary_and_Artistic_Works

Answer (score 2):

Copyright & licensing are separate issues.  Copyright prevents unauthorized duplication of your software/website.  By default, nobody can copy and use your software because of copyright.

A license defines the terms under which you allow people to use the software.  It also defines & limits what your obligations to the user are.  Generally there's language in there to stop them from suing you if the software breaks.

They're both important.  I suggest getting a lawyer if you're releasing it commercially - if you're releasing it for free, I strongly suggest going with a standard open source license.

Comment: Nice explaination, thanks! +1, but I am just going to release some small application to try out for fun. :)